# directives inside ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a problem using directive inside ngRepeat. i cant get value of $scope.files. its undefined when using inside ngrepeat but works properly if ngrepeat not used. cant figure it out. help much appreciated.

$scope.files is undefined while used inside ng-repeat. if not used inside works perfectly

```
<button class="btn btn-success login-button" ng-click="addassignment()">+</button>
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat = "assignment in assignments">
        <td><input class = "filegap" type = "file" file-model="form.cv" ng-model="form.cv" ng-file-select="fileselected(newemp.email)" file-input="files" multiple/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

javascript:

```
app.directive('fileInput', ['$parse', function($parse, $compile){
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        link:function(scope,elm,attrs){
            elm.bind('change', function(){
                $parse(attrs.fileInput)
                .assign(scope,elm[0].files)
                scope.$apply()
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

controller:

```
$scope.addassignment = function(){
    if(typeof $scope.assignments == 'undefined'){
        $scope.assignments = [];
    }
    $scope.assignments.push({});
}
console.log($scope.files);
```

Comment: where is assignments defined ?

Comment: assignments is defined in the controller for dynamic generation of the input. thats not the problem problem is with the directive file-input inside ng-repeat.

Comment: I find this code you gave really hard to follow.. could you maybe offer more info on what you're trying to achieve ? for each assignment upload a file ? all together or individually ?

Comment: `ng-repeat` creates child scopes so unless you have an array or object already defined in scope that the child scope will inherit, it will only be available at the child level, such as in your directive

Comment: does it work outside ng-repeat ? you better create a plunk/jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You don't create a files variable on the main scope, and when you use the assign it will assign to a newly created files (not on the controller), I have modified your code a bit,

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('Main', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.files = [];
  $scope.addAssignment = function(){
    if(typeof $scope.assignments == 'undefined'){
        $scope.assignments = [];
    }
    console.log('add');
    $scope.assignments.push({});
  }
  console.log($scope.files);
  $scope.$watch('files.length', function() {
    console.log($scope.files);
  });
}]).directive('fileInput', [function() {
  return {
        restrict:'A',
        link:function(scope,elm,attrs){
                var files = scope[attrs['fileInput']];
            elm.bind('change', function(){
                files.push(this.files);
                scope.$apply()
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

you can take a look here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/mhXKdlDG5lg8Xnw50lua?p=preview

p.s. You can also use scope binding in the directive instead of that $parse.

Also, when you assign directly like that, it will always override the files because of how prototype inheritance work in JS, use objects / arrays instead for assigning values in a deeper scopes (like ng-model / ng-repeat etc)

Comment: Short version: [ng-repeat creates its own scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), so you have to initialize `files` outside of it.

Comment: that console.log must output a file  something like this..FileList {0: File, length: 1, item: function}0: Filelength: 1__proto__: FileList

Comment: Why "must" it? And what's wrong with seeing all of `$scope.files`? And which `console.log`?